# passing string as FontAwesomeIcons

Tags: dart, flutter

am using [font_awesome_flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/font_awesome_flutter) in my app to display some icons..

am getting the name of the icons from json as strings .. how i can pass it to the icon?

there is a way to achieve this?

for example:

am getting from the json:

```
String icon = 'ad';
```

and then i want to use it like this:

```
new Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.icon),
```

i know it doesn't work like this .. but how can i do this? is it doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one way may that help you. edit **font_awesome_flutter.dart** file as following and also access as below.

I just demonstrate with two Icon you can go on with as much as you need or for all.

**font_awesome_flutter.dart**

library font_awesome_flutter;

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/icon_data.dart';

// THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED!

class FontAwesomeIcons {

  static const createDoc = {
    'fiveHundredPx':  IconDataBrands(0xf26e),
    'accessibleIcon':  IconDataBrands(0xf368),
      //.......add all Icons HERE
  };

  static const IconData fiveHundredPx = const IconDataBrands(0xf26e);
  static const IconData accessibleIcon = const IconDataBrands(0xf368);
  static const IconData accusoft = const IconDataBrands(0xf369);
  static const IconData acquisitionsIncorporated = const IconDataBrands(0xf6af);
  static const IconData ad = const IconDataSolid(0xf641);
  static const IconData addressBook = const IconDataRegular(0xf2b9);
  static const IconData solidAddressBook = const IconDataSolid(0xf2b9);
  static const IconData addressCard = const IconDataRegular(0xf2bb);
  static const IconData solidAddressCard = const IconDataSolid(0xf2bb);
  //.......
  //.......add all Icons HERE To as already  in your file
  }
```

Now you can use as Following Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new FontAwesomeGalleryApp());
}

class FontAwesomeGalleryApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Font Awesome Flutter Gallery',
      theme: new ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        iconTheme: new IconThemeData(size: 36.0, color: Colors.black87),
        textTheme: new TextTheme(
          body1: new TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black87),
        ),
      ),
      home: new Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {

  String data = 'fiveHundredPx';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: new Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.createDoc[data.toString()]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I know That This Way is little bit tough but i found this way only.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the unicode data in the Json. For example :

```
static const IconData clock = const IconDataRegular(0xf017);
```

save f017 in the Json.

Later use the following function for conversion into an int.

```
int getHexFromStr(String fontCode) {
  int val = 0;
  int len = fontCode.length;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    int hexDigit = fontCode.codeUnitAt(i);
    if (hexDigit >= 48 && hexDigit <= 57) {
      val += (hexDigit - 48) * (1 << (4 * (len - 1 - i)));
    } else if (hexDigit >= 65 && hexDigit <= 70) {
      // A..F
      val += (hexDigit - 55) * (1 << (4 * (len - 1 - i)));
    } else if (hexDigit >= 97 && hexDigit <= 102) {
      // a..f
      val += (hexDigit - 87) * (1 << (4 * (len - 1 - i)));
    } else {
      throw new FormatException("An error occurred when converting");
    }
  }
  return val;
}
```

And finally use the following :

```
Icon(IconDataSolid(getHexFromStr(' f017')))
```