# How to use Strings to access class members in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, font-awesome

I want to set use Strings from an API as Fontawesome icons. I have added the [`font_awesome_flutter plugin`](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter).
I need to store the icon name in a variable and then create an object from it. I would imagine it to like this:

```dart
String iconfromApi = 'suitcase';
Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.iconfromApi);
```

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929254/passing-string-as-fontawesomeicons

Comment: You have to create your icons list. Now it depends on you how you will create that list either dynamically or statically. By using that list, you have to check conditions using switch statement and it will return Icons according to the matched string. Also, you can handle icon not found case easily, by using default case.

Comment: @RohitSingh I tried that too.. but icon is not displaying in device screen.. So i printed that icon.. it gives ```IconData(U+0F156)``` as response...

Comment: @RohitSingh since we are declaring the icon as ```const``` so we need to restart the application.. cz it assigns the value for varibale while app starts and now it works fine for me... Thank you...!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [described here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34909#issuecomment-432520934), you would need have access to the `dart:mirrors` pacakage, which is not avaible in Flutter.

A solution that would work in Flutter is creating a helper method. This means that you will have to code in cases for all icon names you want to use. If you do not want to write all of that by hand, you can take a look at a package like [`reflectable`](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable) as mentioned in the [GitHub comment](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34909#issuecomment-432520934) or potentially [`source_gen`](https://pub.dev/packages/source_gen) or [`build_runner`](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner), however, I am not sure if the latter two are well suited.

Anyways, what you could also write by hand is a helper function like this:

```dart
IconData fontAwesomeIconFromString(String name) {
  switch (name) {
    case 'suitecase':
      return FontAwesomeIcons.suitecase;
    case 'gamepad':
      return FontAwesomeIcons.gamepad;
    // ...
  }
}
```

In your code, you can now use it like this:

```dart
String iconfromApi = 'suitcase';
Icon(fontAwesomeIconFromString(iconFromApi));
```

Comment: it sounds good... it suits for less icons.. but in large cases means how can we go..?